# Update : pytorch : mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied in maxpoolid

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

From the keras code [here](https://github.com/zelezniak-lab/param_pipeline/blob/random_search_with_replicates/models/THIS_CNN_NN_vals_input.py#L81), I was translating to pytorch code. However I am facing the bottleneck regarding my `MaxPool1d()` after Conv1d, batchnorm1d and dropouts.

The code :

```
from typing import List
class DNA_CNN_test2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_len: int,
                 num_filters: List[int] = [32, 64,128],
                 kernel_size: int = 3,
                 p = 0.2):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        # CNN module
        self.conv_net = nn.Sequential()
        num_filters = [4] + num_filters
        for idx in range(len(num_filters) - 1):
            self.conv_net.add_module(
                f"conv_{idx}",
                nn.Conv1d(num_filters[idx], num_filters[idx + 1],
                          kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
            )
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"relu_{idx}", nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"batchNor_{idx}",nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters[idx + 1]))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"dropout_{idx}",nn.Dropout(0.2))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"MaxP_{idx}",nn.MaxPool1d(4,stride= 4))
        self.conv_net.add_module("flatten", nn.Flatten())
        self.conv_net.add_module("linear",nn.Linear(num_filters[-1]*seq_len//4**(len(num_filters) - 1), 1))
        
    def forward(self, xb: torch.Tensor):
        """Forward pass."""
        xb = xb.permute(0, 2, 1) 
        out = self.conv_net(xb)
        return out
```

When I run my code, I get the error:

```
 mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2048x2048 and 2000x1)
```

I have already tried many suggestions from answers to similar questions, but none of them worked. Any suggestions about what I should do?

Comment: You need to account for the fact that max_pooling with a stride of 4 reduces the sequence length by a factor of 4, and scale the input dimension of the Linear layer accordingly.

Comment: as there are 3 layers 4^3 =64. I applied `self.conv_net.add_module("linear",nn.Linear(num_filters[-1]*seq_len/64, 1))`, however getting error ` empty(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type float at pos 2`

Comment: Try: `num_filters[-1]*seq_len // 64` with a `//` to make integer division. By the way you should use a constant that take into account of the number of layer instead of 64 like `4**(len(num_filters) - 1)`

Comment: I do understand that I need to change the input size for linear by stride, however it seems that the shapes are not matching, Do I need to configurate the size of conv1d after every maxpool1d ?

Comment: `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2048x2048 and 2000x1)` is the error i am having now.

Comment: Do i have to adjust the seqlength? I tried nn.lear(2048,1) for testing and it works, however it seems underfitting as validation loss is higher than training loss

Comment: That would be overfitting, not underfitting, and that is no longer a programming problem.